# Why does concat on vectors evaluate to a list?

Tags: clojure

Calling concat on vectors returns a list. Being a total noob I would expect that the result would also be a vector. Why the conversion to list?

Example:

```
user=> (concat [1 2] [3 4] [5 6])
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
; Why not: [1 2 3 4 5 6] ?
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

concat returns a lazy sequence.

```
user=> (doc concat)
-------------------------
clojure.core/concat
([] [x] [x y] [x y & zs])
  Returns a lazy seq representing the concatenation of the elements in the supplied colls.
```

you can convert it back to a vector with into:

```
user=> (into [] (concat [1 2] [3 4] [5 6]))
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

into uses transients so it's pretty quick about it.

Comment: There's also `vec` for slightly shorter code with very similar performance.

Comment: I believe the 'why' is because it returns a LazySeq, which is not really a list. Besides, Clojure vectors are not lazy. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12206806/1814970.

Comment: The `concat` returnes only a sequence as mentioned in its `doc`.
as  Michal mentioned already, you can send the result of your `concat` to the `vec` function the get a vector back:
`(vec (concat [1 2] [3 4] [5 6]))` (Thank you @Mars for your suggestion)